# Windows 10 USB bottlenecking

Tags: windows-10, usb, performance, boot-camp

I have a 128gb MacBook Pro and I wanted to run Windows for gaming. Because I have 128gb (and Boot Camp requires 50gb of internal hard drive space), I decided to run Windows from external USB. It boots up and works fine technically, however, there seems to be some bottlenecking going on. At first glance everything seems to be running smooth - the cursor moves across the screen seamlessly and my resolution is great. But, when I perform an action, lets say opening File Explorer or CMD or going to IE (or whatever its called now), speeds drop. For example, I click File Explorer and nothing happens so I click it again and about 15 seconds later two File Explorers open up.

So, why is this happening? I'm using USB 3.0 and it said on packaging that it has transfer speeds up to 130mb/s. Does the problem lie in the USB? My laptop should be plenty capable of running Windows 10. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: "My laptop should be plenty capable of running Windows 10. " - It would run it perfectly fine if you installed it on a HDD/SSD but `Windows to Go` installation (which is basically what you are using) have specific hardware requirements and it appears your USB drive does not meet those requirements.

Comment: The packaging can say anything. Did you run any real benchmarks on your USB drive? I am sure that the 130 MB/s is for transferring huge sequential files. The Windows makes access by much smaller chunks, so performance usually drops to a crawl. It is difficult to compete with internal SSDs with 500-600MB/s throughput and sizable cache buffering. Also, you likely have some antivirus stuff, which might treat removable media differently and scan it every time, so the 15 seconds come.

Comment: Do you think [this USB drive](http://usb.userbenchmark.com/SanDisk-Extreme-USB-30-32GB/Rating/1466) would fix my problem? *edit: I'll run a speed test on my Samsung right now, do I wanna look for sequential speed?